# Is there any way to translate a .cubin to .ptx

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, disassembly

I got a .cubin file, but I couldn't understand the sass code from it(like ISCADD R26,R21,R2,0x2), there were no detailed information from nvidia website. So I think maybe the ptx file could be more readabile.

Comment: SASS is proprietary and specific to every architecture. Exact mappings to PTX are unknown in both directions. However you should have PTX generated if you build from source code yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to "translate" any SASS you obtain from a CUBIN file by disassembly to PTX.

However, CUBIN files can (depending on how they were compiled) contain PTX code. `cuobjdump` can extract and display any embedded PTX from a CUBIN file with the `-ptx` option (see [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#cuobjdump)).